# How to wait in watir-webdriver to load next page and then do assert on some random text

Tags: watir-webdriver

I am new to watir, and (believe me) I tried all the options that are avaliable here for adding wait and assert but have not been successful in doing so.

Here's a brief description of what I'm trying to do and appreciate your help.

1. I log into my website
2. I login using userid/password and hit click button.
3. I want watir to wait until next page is loaded
4. I want to do some assert to verify the login was successful.

My step 3 and step 4 are failing with the error `element not found`.

If I login manually and login is successful, I see text Hello,username at the top of the second page and this is what I've been trying to key off of but not having any success. It could be something very simple, but since I'm new to watir, I'm unable to figure it out.

Here are all the commands I tried:

```
    $b.button(:id, 'usernameLogfaceinButton').click
      #$b.wait_until($b.text.include?("Hello"))
      #($b.text.include?("Hello")).wait_until_present
      #$b.text_field(:text, "Hello").wait_until_present

    if $b.text.include? "Hello"

      puts "Test Passed. Found the test string: Hello- Actual Results match Expected Results." 

    else
      puts "Test Failed! Could not find: Hello"
    end
```

HTML on Page:

```
<body id="myAccounts" class="cardholderLayout ">
  <div id="content">
    <div id="navigationContainer">
      <div id="headerNavigationMenu" class="innerContents">
        <div class="logo"><img alt="xxx" src="/images/xxx.png?xxxxxxxx"></div>
        <ul class="menu">
          <li class="menuItem">
            <a href="#" class="menuLink">Hello, Bob</a>
```

I hope someone can help me or point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$b.link(:text => /^Hello/).wait_until_present
```

Notice that:

- It is `$b.link` instead of `$b.text_field`. The method needs to match the type of element you are looking for.
- The text in the locator is `/^Hello/` instead of `"Hello"`. If you pass a string (ie `"Hello"`, watir will look for an element where the text **exactly** matches. If you want to do a partial text match, then you need to use a regular expression. The expression `/^Hello/` says to find a text starting with "Hello".

Comment: As usual, @Justin beat me to it.  One suggestion I'd make would be to also look into [rspec](https://github.com/rspec/rspec) (or even Test::Unit).  Either one provides standardized ways of asserting the correct behavior for your web app.

Comment: I used $b.link(:class, 'menuLink').wait_until_present and works.